# Looking for a way to exclude files used by geninfo/genhtml

Tags: html, gcc, gcov, lcov

We are trying to use geninfo and genhtml (alternative to gcovr, see [here](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/genhtml.1.php)) to produce an html page using coverage provided by gcov.

- `geninfo` creates lcov-tracefiles from gcov's *.gcda files
- `genhtml` generates html files from the above tracefiles

However, the end result includes not only our code, but also files from /usr/include.

Does anyone know of a way to exclude these?

I tried looking at the man page but could not find anything http://linux.die.net/man/1/geninfo

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [lcov](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lcov) `-r` option to remove those files you aren't interested in.

```
lcov -r <input tracefile> /usr/include/\* -o <output tracefile>
```

Answer (score 23):

If you're just looking to ignore files from /usr/include, a better option is probably "--no-external", [which is intended for exactly this purpose](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcov.1.php).

```
lcov --no-external -d $(BLD_DIR) --capture -o .coverage.run
```

Comment: And as an extra: if you are building out-of-source builds; you can set source directories with `--directory` flag as much as you need, so that correct sources are found - because others will be omitted.